# How to keep JMS Headers after Unmarshalling their Xml payload in spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration, unmarshalling, spring-jms

I am sending JMS messages with XML payloads and some custom headers `contentType` with values `text/json` and `text/xml` using Jmeter.

My Spring integration configuration looks like this:

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter channel="jmsInChannel" destination-name="queue.demo" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory1" />
<int:channel id="jmsInChannel" />

<int:header-value-router input-channel="jmsInChannel" header-name="contentType" default-output-channel="nullChannel">
    <int:mapping value="text/json" channel="jsonTransformerChannel" />
    <int:mapping value="text/xml" channel="xmlTransformerChannel" />
</int:header-value-router>
```

Up to this point, everything works perfectly, the messages are successfully routed to their respective transformers.

My problem is, when it's an XML payload I first used a JAXB Unmarshaller along with `<ixml:unmarshalling-transofmer ../>` provided by `http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml`.

I could get the payload, but it couldn't process the message afterwards as a JMS message, it became a pure POJO. So I lost the headers, and I couldn't use `<int: ../>` components without serializing the POJO, which is not what I wanted to achieve.

I have found a work-around, where I defined my own Unmarshalling bean in java like so:

```
<int:channel id="xmlTransformerChannel" />
<int:transformer input-channel="xmlTransformerChannel" ref="xmlMsgToCustomerPojoTransformer" output-channel="enrichInChannel" />
```

method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Message transform(String message) {

    logger.info("Message Received \r\n" + message);

    try {
        MyModel myModel = (MyModel) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(message)));
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(myModel).build();

    } catch (XmlMappingException e) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(e).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(e).build();
    }
}
```

I could successfully process the message as a Spring integration Message, but I lost the original custom JMS headers.

In contrast, all I had to do to transform the json payloads and keep the Message format AND preserving my custom headers is this xml configuration:

```
<int:channel id="jsonTransformerChannel" />
<int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="jsonTransformerChannel" output-channel="enrichInChannel" type="com.alrawas.ig5.MyModel" />
```

My question is, how to keep the original custom JMS headers after unmarshalling the xml payload?

**UPDATE:**

I did try to write the xml transformer this way, taking Message as input instead of only string, it did not throw exception in this method, but it did later in the routing phase

```
public Message<?> transform(Message<String> message) {

    logger.info("Message Received \r\n" + message);

    try {
        MyModel myModel = (MyModel) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(message.getPayload())));
        return (Message<MyModel>) MessageBuilder.withPayload(myModel).copyHeaders(message.getHeaders()).build();

    } catch (XmlMappingException e) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(e).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(e).build();
    }
}
```

I ran into a problem in a component I use later in this flow:

```
<int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="outr" output-channel="outch" />
<int:router method="route" input-channel="outch" default-output-channel="nullChannel">
    <bean class="com.alrawas.ig5.MyCustomRouter" />
</int:router>
```

In my route method threw Cannot cast String to com.alrawas.ig5.MyModel Exception:

```
public class MyCustomRouter {

    public String route(Message<MyModel> myModel) {

    Integer tenNumber = myModel.getPayload().getNumber(); // <-- Cast Exception here
    System.out.println(myModel);
    return (tenNumber % 10 == 0) ? "stayLocal" : "goRemote";

    }
}
```

This Cast Exception only happens after unmarshalling xml, JSON payloads work fine without losing headers or throwing cast exceptions.

**UPDATE:**

Check my answer below: [contentType was not really a **custom** header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57866829/3367392)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you develop custom `transformer`, you need to keep in mind that returning a `Message<?>` leads you to a fully control over its content.

When transformer function returns a `Message`, it doesn't populate any request headers.

So, your `public Message transform(String message) {` must expect a `Message` as an input and you need to copy all the headers from the request message to reply message. There are appropriate methods on the `MessageBuilder`.

On the other hand it is fully unclear why do you need to return a `Message` here since everything in the Spring Integration is going to be wrapped to `Message` before sending to the output channel.

Comment: I updated my question, additionally to the updated question, I did try to make the transformer return MyModel, I still got ClassCastException in the router later.

Comment: But you have to JSON transformer just before that router. So, your pojo is transformed into String. Is that what you want?

Comment: I went for making my own xml unmarshaller transformer instead of `<ixml:unmarshalling-transofmer ../>` because when I tried using my `<int:object-to-json-transformer../>` followed by my custom `<int:router ../>` it threw a string to MyModel ClassCastException in the router when I tried to access the Model.

Comment: It worked first with json, usign object-to-json after using json-to-object, did not cause the router later to throw ClassCastException. I wonder why when the payload was originally xml, `object-to-json` transformation made it so the next router could not do the casting like it did with originally json payloads

Comment: Not Really, I think I should post a new question specifically about what I described in my last comment, which was the original reason why I dug into this matter using this junk approach.

Comment: Ok. I’ve answered you about headers and class cast. Please, ask a new SO question for other stuff

Answer (score 0):

The take:

The ClassCastException was happening later in the last router, was because I named my custom header `contentType`. Which was a default jms header used internally. When I changed its value to `text/xml`, that last router `String route(Message<MyModel> myModel)` was trying to cast the json into MyModel, and it failed because the header was no more `application/json` like it should be, it was `text/xml`. Which caused the  ClassCastException.

So I got rid of the custom xml unmarshalling logic bean. I renamed my custom header. And used `<ixml:unmarshalling-transformer ../>`.

It worked using xml configuration without additional custom java beans.